# How to get speech output of negative numbers using festival speech synthesis?

Tags: text-to-speech

For example, the speech output of -5.6 is "five point six", not "negative five point six". The negative part is always missing.
How to get speech output of negative numbers using festival speech synthesis?

Comment: Can you preprocess the text to speak in advance and replace "-5.6" with "negative 5.6" literally? That should be easy by running it through  something like `sed s/\B-([0-9])/negative \1/'` without having to know anything about how `festival` works.

Comment: @ Byte Commander I have already tried that.  What I have done resulted in reading "dot" instead of "point", ie  "negative five dot six" instead of "negative five point six".

Comment: @ Byte Commander Yep... That works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ByteCommander that looks very much like an answer to me. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @DavidFoerster that looks very much like an answer to me. Why not post it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speech synthesis engine may produce more appropriate results if the input data uses an actual minus sign “−” (U+2212) to prefix negative numbers.

To replace all dashes “-” (U+002D) in front of digits with minus signs you may use this substitution command:

```sh
sed -re 's/\B-([0-9])/−\1/g' input.txt > output.txt
```